# Runing one thread at a time on TaskScheduler (STA thread)

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library, taskfactory

I have set [StaTaskScheduler](https://github.com/nicman2006/Orchard-CMS/blob/e26862c9c6fecad82d4094e252882b8d87941614/Modules/Piedone.HelpfulLibraries/Libraries/ParallelExtensionsExtras/TaskSchedulers/StaTaskScheduler.cs) threads to 1 and I expected that I would get one Debug output every 5 seconds, but I end up with 10 with the same date

```
private void Test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(5000); //temp for long operation
            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, MainWindow.MyStaThread);
}

public static StaTaskScheduler MyStaThread = 
        new StaTaskScheduler(numberOfThreads: 1);
```

What am I missing? The reason for STA is that later it will be used for Icons extraction needing STA, but this test is to check it is done in sequence.

Comment: What is ur expected output ?? Printing  DateTime.Now every 5 seconds. Didnt get u

Comment: Your assumption that `Task.Delay` emulates an long running operation is incorrect. The `Task.Delay` is timer based and doesn't block the thread which called it, so your tasks complete one by one but almost immediately. So not surprisingly you observe the same timestamp for them.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov Thanks, it was supposed to be `Thread.Sleep(2500);` and it works then

Answer (score -2):

you have to start tasks using the `MyStaThred.QueueTask` rather then `Task.Factory.Startnew`:

```
private void Test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        MyStaThread.QueueTask(new Task(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(5000); //temp for long operation
            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }));
}

public static StaTaskScheduler MyStaThread = 
        new StaTaskScheduler(numberOfThreads: 1);
```

`Task.Factory.Startnew` uses .Net Framework internal thread pool and does not take the `StaTaskScheduler` into account.

Comment: this won't solve the problem Task.Delay doesn't lock the thead